# C++ GTest error "ld: library not found for -lgtest" on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, googletest, clion

I try to include gtest to my C++ project. The IDE I'm using is CLion. I have this in my CMAKE

```
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/lib)
```

and this in the file that I'm working on

`#include "gtest/gtest.h"`

I have installed gtest in the Terminal using these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest
cd googletest
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
```

I'm assume that's enough to use gtest, but the Compiler says otherwise. This is the error message that I receive

```
ld: library not found for -lgtest
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix it? Any attempt is appreciated!

Solution: I follow the direction on the README.md file from googletest github page and it works like a charm.  https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md

Comment: Investigate where `make install` installed it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the **complete** CMake file in your question post. This will help make the problem more clear so we can provide better solutions.

Comment: Hi @drescherjm, I'm pretty sure is in "/usr/local/include", I even try to copy the path from the file "/Users/myusername/googletest/googletest/include"

Comment: Then check for the libraries at `/usr/local/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

Usually gtest is a static library, so you need to specify libgtest.a, something like this:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -pedantic-errors test.cpp /usr/lib/libgtest.a -o test
```

Comment: Hi @artm, thanks for the suggestion. I try that command in the terminal but receive these errors:

`clang: error: no such file or directory: 'test.cpp'        
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/lib/libgtest.a'        
clang: error: no input files`        

Do I need to run this in a specific directory? and will I need to change those filenames to match my actual file?

Answer (score 0):

I follow the direction on the README.md file from googletest github page and it works like a charm. https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to:

```
brew install googletest
```

for me this step didnt work as it should have
so on some apple forum find out some thoughts that it can be some specific problems for big sur for example

For this I chose worse variant but this working for me:
adding googletest as submodule in git

```
git submodule init
git submodule add https://github.com/google/googletest.git googletest
cd googletest
git checkout [target_version]
```

also in cmake file there re should be these lines:

```
add_subdirectory(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest"
    "googletest"
)
```

if you just git cloned your project so you should write in console:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

my project hierarchy looks like that:

```
MyString
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
│   └──...
├── googletest
├── tests
│   └── MyStringTests.cpp
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── MyString.h
    └── MyString.cpp
```

Comment: at this point, why would you not just use fetchcontent?

Comment: @starball whats the difference? Dont know anything about this method.
I decided to do so cuz i want to develop project for crossplatform and this case i used submodule as exception. In general prefer to use precompiled variant as the case was described in topic.